# How to get user name from Apple login

Tags: ios, authentication

How can I get the user's name in apple login response? I set scope as "name email", but the response contains an email only within JWT encoded id_token and no user name.

I tried to click on "stop using apple id" for the app and it helps to get the real email address, but anyway there is no username.

Comment: The claims in the Sign In with Apple JWT are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple). There is no user name. The `sub` claim is all you need to uniquely identify a user in your app.

Comment: I don't say about unique identifier, I need to display user name. And if there is not username, why iOS asks it when I click on Login with Apple? And why there is the fullName scope?

Comment: If you request the full name scope then Apple requests that user provides one when they initially Sign In with Apple. Apple does not store this value. This value is provided in the initial [`ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidcredential). Your app needs to store this securely as it will not be provided in subsequent authentications.

Comment: Is it possible to take the same response on the backend side? From here https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token

Comment: If you are using the javascript API, it would help if you added those tags to your question.  The [`SiginInResponse`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/signinresponsei) you receive from the initial "Sign up with Apple" request contains a `UserI` object with a `name` property.  As with the mobile framework you must capture the name from this initial sign up event.  It is not saved by Apple and is therefore unable to be presented on subsequent requests.